# Tomcat not responding on localhost, but working through apache2/mod_jk

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, networking, mod-jk

Tomcat is not responing to calls to localhost:8080

```
curl -k https://localhost/user-service/1/user
```

works fine, but

```
curl localhost:8080/user-service/1/user
```

hangs for hours and never responds.

```
netstat -tnlp
```

shows

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1504/sshd
>   tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1559/apache2
>   tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      19341/java
>   tcp6       0      0 :::46467                :::*                    LISTEN      19341/java
>   tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      19341/java
>   tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      19341/java
>   tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      19341/java
>   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1559/apache2

but the localhost call doesn't even show up in the localhost access logs

We are running apache2, mod_jk, and tomcat8.

I see no errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your tomcat instance is expecting a IPv6 address connection to port 8080 (tcp6 denotes ipv6 connection).

To solve this in your `TOMCAT_HOME\bin` directory create a file called `setenv.sh` (if it doesn't already exist) and add the following

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
```

This will make tomcat bind to IPv4 upon restart.

You can check this by running your netstat command again and instead of seeing `tcp6` for `8080` it should just say `tcp`

Comment: 1. The address attribute of a Connector can be used to specify an IPv4 or IPv6 address.

Comment: 2. IIRC, a Java connector implementation ("Nio", "Nio2") will bind to both IPv4 and IPv6 address by default ("dual" feature).
3. The Tomcat-Native connector ("Apr") is known to bind to one network only (either IPv4 or IPv6). I think it is not controllable by "java.net" system properties.

4. In OP's netstat listing HTTPD appears to listen on IPv6 only - as well as Tomcat. I wonder why connection to HTTPD succeeds, if it is really an IPv4 vs IPv6 issue.

Comment: I had to add those `java_opts` as specified to my tomcat instance to get it to bind to ipv4 as I was running into the same issue with my local tomcat instance. Could be the reason why httpd succeeded was because it was looking at both the ipv4 and ipv6 connection and doing the translation while tomcat was strictly set to ipv6